# mod and case not working together for delphi

Tags: delphi, switch-statement, case, modulo

I'm trying to make a calculator at delphi but I have a problem in the mod area, I haven't found how to solve it.

```
procedure TfrmHesapMakinesi.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
sayi1:double;
sayi2:double;
sonuc:double;
islem:byte;
begin
       islem:=(Sender as TButton).Tag;
       sayi1:=strtofloatdef(edtSayi1.Text,0);
       sayi2:=strtofloatdef(edtSayi2.Text,0);
   case islem of
    1:sonuc:=sayi1+sayi2;
    2:sonuc:=sayi1-sayi2;
    3:sonuc:=sayi1*sayi2;
    4:sonuc:=sayi1/sayi2;
    5:sonuc:=sayi1 mod sayi2; //ERROR
  else
    ShowMessage('İşlem seçiniz');
  end;
       lblsonuc.Caption:=floattostr(sonuc);


end;
```

Comment: What's the error you get? Are we supposed to guess?

Comment: Please don't ask about errors but not tell us about the error, #dv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the future, please specify an error you got.

But in this case it is easy to undestand the error. **mod** operator works with integer variables only, and you have `double`. You can write:

```
sonuc:= sayi1 - int(sayi1 / sayi2) * sayi2;
```